# Scaling Vectorized Text proportionately

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, resize

I would like to know if there is a way to scale two separate pieces of text that have been vectorized so that they still look proportionate to each other when one of the words has letters with ascenders and descenders.

[image: Scaled Text]

In my first example you can see how all the letters inside the baseline line up.  In my second example I scaled each of the text graphics to 1 inch in height maintaining proportions, yet because the "h" and the "p" both extend outside the baseline illustrator takes the measurement from those two letters, and it looks off.  Is there a way to scale from within the baseline, and make any ascenders and descenders scale proportionately?

Comment: what software are you using, Illustrator? Photoshop? Why do you need to select them separately?

Answer (score 1):

Select both texts and group (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) them together. This will maintain same size of both elements. You can scale by inputing values in the **Transform Panel** (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>) or manually by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and dragging one of the four element boundary box corners. After that, you can ungroup them (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut to do what you want, but you can make use of some guides.

You've already got baseline and x-height guides, so just add some ascender and descender guides too...

[image]